# Add tableview as datasource to jasper report

Tags: java, javafx, jasper-reports, tableview

i dont know if this is possible, but i would like to fill jasper report from tableview.
I have tableview, and my tableview has filter, what i want to accomplish is when table is filtered and user press button, that i fill jasper report with that data.

So is it possible just to pass tableview.getitems as data source, or whole table model.
And if it is how would i add then fields to jasper report designer so that i can arrange them.

I tried to pass:

```
JasperPrint jrPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, tableview.getItems());
```

....
  But i just get null values...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found solution, instead using JasperReports i started using 
DynamicJasper.

http://dynamicjasper.com/

it does everything i wanted and much more, if anyone else needs i provided link